# Update Twitter Status using CURL

Tags: twitter, status

I have a problem while updating twitter status by username and password.

Here is the Code for that:

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$message = 'Testing';
$url = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml';

$curl_handle = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); //basic authentication
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "status=$message");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);

curl_close($curl_handle);

echo $buffer;
```

This is not for only one user so that I can not use OAuth(means using consumer key and other token). I have already tried this: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/how-to-update-twitter-using-php-and-twitter-api/  but i can not pass multiple user's username and password for updating multiple twitter status.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to update  twitter status by username and password via curl any more - basic authentication was [deprecated/turned off by Twitter](http://blog.twitter.com/2010/08/twitter-applications-and-oauth.html) several months ago (August 2010). Updates and such by third party applications now have to be done via oauth authentication.

By the way - considering you're using PHP - I'd suggest using either the [PEAR Services_Twitter](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Twitter/) package or [the Zend equivalent](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html).

Comment: Thanks for this information. 

I viewed both of the links that you gave me. But I want to update twitter status for multiple users using their username and password dynamically.

I will have twitter username and password of different users. So Is there any help on web to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use user name and password to update a Twitter status no matter how many users you have. This no longer works. It has been turned off. You must use OAuth. OAuth allows multiple users to log into Twitter on your site. When they do that, you get a copy of their OAuth tokens. You then use these tokens to send tweets to their accounts. You will still find documentation for using basic authentication to do this online, but all of these are out of date. Basic authentication is no longer available on Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use cookie each time you update user status, then destroy cookie after each success status update.
Second, put this condition in loop to update all user's you wont.
See this may help you:
http://blancer.com/tutorials/73877/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/

Comment: When I have used this CURL code then it will display error: "Basic authentication is not supported" so can you help me on this.